# Joining Tables with the Same Data But Different Column Names

Tags: sql

coachID and teamCoach contain the same data but have different column names. I'm having trouble joining them as a result. What can I do?

```
SELECT tblCoaches.coachID AS "Coach ID", 
       tblCoaches.coachName AS "Coach Name", 
       tblCoaches.coachCity AS "Coach City", 
       tblTeams.teamName AS "Team Name"
FROM tblCoaches
INNER JOIN tblTeams ON **tblCoaches.coachID = tblTeams.teamCoach**
      AND (coachID IN (SELECT teamCoach FROM tblTeams))
WHERE teamIsRec IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make join on specific columns:

```
select * from table2 JOIN table1 ON table2.id = table1.id_a
```

In your case, I think that the line

```
AND (coachID IN (SELECT teamCoach FROM tblTeams))
```

doesn't perform any logic because INNER JOIN takes only those column values that are both in two tables. So you syntax should looks like:

```
SELECT tblCoaches.coachID AS "Coach ID", tblCoaches.coachName AS "Coach Name", tblCoaches.coachCity AS "Coach City", tblTeams.teamName AS "Team Name"
FROM tblCoaches
INNER JOIN tblTeams ON tblCoaches.coachID = tblTeams.teamCoach
WHERE teamIsRec IS NULL;
```

Comment: Okay, so as long as the data is the same, it doesn't matter that the names don't match. Thank you!

Comment: Good job for copying my answer

Comment: Or maybe you mine?

Answer (score 0):

This structure should work

```
    SELECT
      tblCoaches.coachID AS "Coach ID",
      tblCoaches.coachName AS "Coach Name",
      tblCoaches.coachCity AS "Coach City",
      tblTeams.teamName AS "Team Name"
    FROM tblCoaches
    INNER JOIN tblTeams
      ON tblCoaches.coachID = tblTeams.teamCoach   -- IDs that linked the tables
    WHERE teamIsRec IS NULL;
```

Comment: So you removed the `AND` statement (which I kind of just threw in there, to be honest), but I've already tried that. It doesn't give me any results. Regardless, it's acceptable to say `ON tblCoaches.coachID = tblTeams.teamCoach`? Even though the column names aren't the same?

Comment: You did not post your table definition, how can I tell if you did the right join.... i.e. if `TeamCoach` is an `ID` then should be able to join it with the `CoachID` otherwise replace teamcoach with something else that identifies the coach